# ClickOnce смена url установки

Tags: c#, clickonce

Добрый день. В ClickOnce пытаюсь консольно сменить Installation Folder
[image: Installation Folder]

Для этих целей есть класс, который создает тестовый манифест, где меняет его DeploymentUrl

```
   public static void UpdateURL(/*string certificatePassword, string certificateFilePath,*/ /*string manifestFilePath,*/ string url)
    {
        var manifestFilePath = @"c:\Tests\OwinSelfHostSample.application";

        string password = "Password";

        // Open the deployment file (.application)

        DeployManifest deployManifest = ManifestReader.ReadManifest(manifestFilePath, false) as DeployManifest;

        // Set the URL to the new url:

        deployManifest.DeploymentUrl = url;

        // Create a new manifest file (in a temp folder)

        string tempFileName = @"c:\Tests\newManifest.application";

        ManifestWriter.WriteManifest(deployManifest, tempFileName);

        // Sign the certificate again

        string certFilePath = @"c:\users\hobrus\source\repos\OwinSelfHostSample\OwinSelfHostSample\OwinSelfHostSample_TemporaryKey.pfx";

        // Make sure the entered cert file exists

        if (File.Exists(certFilePath))

        {

            // Construct cert object for cert

            X509Certificate2 cert;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))

            {

                cert = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath);

            }

            else

            {

                cert = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, password);

            }

            SecurityUtilities.SignFile(cert, null, tempFileName);

            Console.WriteLine("Signed! new file: " + tempFileName);

        }
    }
}
```

Но в итоге падает с ошибкой

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Tests\OwinSelfHostSample.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + You cannot start application OwinSelfHostSample from this location because it is already installed from a different location.
        + You cannot start application OwinSelfHostSample from location file:///C:/Tests/OwinSelfHostSample.application it is already installed from location http://f15535be.ngrok.io/OwinSelfHostSample.application. You can start it from location http://f15535be.ngrok.io/OwinSelfHostSample.application or you can uninstall it and reinstall it from location file:///C:/Tests/OwinSelfHostSample.application. If you reinstall the application, be aware that you might lose any customizations that you made to the application.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что приложение уже установлено у вас на компьютере и его надо предварительно удалить?

Comment: С удалением тоже не пойдет, одна из фишек ClickOnce, то, что он докачивает только те файлы, которые изменились, а остальные берет из тех, что уже были, каждый раз перекачивать проект слишком затратно

Comment: Вот только для установки из разных источников это, по всей видимости (а именно сообщению об ошибке), не работает.

Comment: Проверил сегодня с удалением(Хоть это и не подходит для финальной версии), даже переустановив, он будет падать с ошибкой. Users\AppData\Local\Apps так же чистил

Comment: С этой же ошибкой?

Comment: Что то вроде not valid manifest, однако это копия манифеста который работает, но в котором поменяли url, но переподписали валидным ключом

Comment: Думаю, это и описание ошибки стоит добавить в вопрос.